# Cannot do passwordless SSH login to MacOS

Tags: macos, ssh, openssh, macos-mojave

I want to login to my MacBook Prob via SSH without a password but using a RSA key pair. However even I added my public key to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, logging in to my MacOS is still requiring a password. Here is a reproducible commands sequence, running on my MacOS:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ ssh localhost -v
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'jasonmiu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:7QVvRsi/mPrgwPil4W7FmlyyimpDC8QiAApfwzXbKqQ
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:wFRcKxEUX+Y0FVLDUMv+GMZN60WWUHqAUaaKztEGMbU
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:wFRcKxEUX+Y0FVLDUMv+GMZN60WWUHqAUaaKztEGMbU
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
```

In my /etc/ssh/sshd_config, I have enabled the options:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
```

The same commands work on my another Linux machine. My MacOS version is 10.14.4 Mojave.

Here is my output of "$ ls -al"

```
$ ls -al
total 32
drwx------   6 jasonmiu  staff   192 Apr 12 03:50 .
drwxrwxrwx  73 jasonmiu  staff  2336 Apr 12 18:26 ..
-rw-------   1 jasonmiu  staff   403 Apr 12 03:50 authorized_keys
-rw-------   1 jasonmiu  staff  1831 Apr 12 03:50 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--   1 jasonmiu  staff   403 Apr 12 03:50 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 jasonmiu  staff   171 Apr 12 03:50 known_hosts
```

Comment: Could you run "ls -la" on your .ssh folder and [edit] your question to include the output?

Answer (score 4):

Along with all the options provided in @4symm3trica1's answer, you should also append one more line to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, i.e.

```
 RSAAuthentication yes
 PubkeyAuthentication yes
 AuthorizedKeysFile /Users/abhishek/.ssh/authorized_keys
 ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
 PasswordAuthentication no
 UsePAM no
 StrictModes no
```

And then restart the sshd daemon in Mac using the following commands:

```
 sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
 sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify/add the following values in/to your sshd_config:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

That should disable password authentication.

Set the directory permissions to

```
sudo chown -R jasonmiu /Users/jasonmiu/
sudo chmod 700 /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh
sudo chmod 600 /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And also check if remote login in System Preferences/Sharing is enabled and your user is added there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I changed the "sshd_config" as you suggested, ssh to my MacOS does not ask password, but "Permission denied": `$ ssh localhost -v
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3 ...  ...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jasonmiu/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
jasonmiu@localhost: Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Ok, check my edited answer

Comment: thanks for your update. However, the same problem persists after I have changed the ownership and permission.

Comment: maybe an issue with your key pair?  Does your authorized_keys file begin with "ssh-rsa ..."? Unwanted blanks? You could create a new pair.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a new Mojave Macbook pro for testing this issue, and this SSHD issue does not happen on this new Majava MBP. So I decided to reinstall the MacOS from scratch on my MBP. After reinstallation, the issue has gone. So I *guess* this SSHD cannot be connected with an RSA key pair issue was introduced in the previous upgrades.

This is not a perfect solution but works for me. Thanks for all the answer from everyone.